# Dynamically fill mvvm model from indexed array

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

`GetAirports` lets me fill `_airports` if it were to be unindexed this meaning I could also get an airport if I were to use `_airport[0]`

But getting the airports with this public API link https://desktopapps.ryanair.com/en-gb/res/stations uses an indexed array with objects assigned to them. How can I dynamically **fill** `_airports` and **extract** them without knowing the actual index name?

```
public async Task<List<Airports>> GetAirports()
{
    string url = _BASEURL;
    if( _airports == null)
        _airports = await GetAsync<List<Airports>>(url);

    return _airports;
}
```

GetAsync function:

```
protected async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = CreateHttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

Airport model:

```
public class Airports
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

From the API

```
"AAL":{
    "name":"Aalborg Airport",
    "country":"DK",
    "timeZone":"DK",
    "latitude":"570535N",
    "longitude":"0095100E"
},
"AAR":{...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a work around based on the format of the data returned from the API.

Add an additional property to the model to hold the key/code like `AAL`

```
public class Airport { //<-- note the name change of the model
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Next refactor the parsing to use `Dictionary<string, Airport>` and then extract the `KeyValuePair`s to return the desired type

```
public async Task<List<Airport>> GetAirportsAsync() { //<-- note the name change
    string url = _BASEURL;
    if( _airports == null) {
        var data = await GetAsync<Dictionary<string, Airport>>(url);
        _airports = data.Select(_ => {
            var code = _.Key;
            var airport = _.Value;
            airport.Code = code;
            return airport;
        }).ToList();
    }

    return _airports;
}
```

Comment: Good thing to have a workaround but it there a way too keep the API format the same in the actual code? I can definitely use the workaround though

Comment: @Wanjia then just return the `Dictionary<string, Airport>`. I suggested the workaround because you were using `List<Airport>` in the provided example.